# calculated width for an absolute position

Tags: css

I am trying to give my **:after** a calculated width using `calc(100%-4px)` but since it is `position:absolute` this is not working.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u86zy0fh/)

```css
article {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #FF9800, rgba(255, 235, 59, .91) 87%), url(http://ably.ir/Uploads/SQL%20Server/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Tutorial.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  color: #263238;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

article:after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100%-4px);
  height: calc(100%-4px);
  background: #263238;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-md-12">
  <h2>something</h2>
</article>
```

[this is what i want](http://fiddle.jshell.net/u86zy0fh/1/show/)

Comment: what about applying it to `right` (Or just: `right: 2px;`)?

Comment: Like the above comment states you should probably instead of using calc set the right to 2px and even the bottom to 2px it will have better browser support as well here is an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/24xe55o7/ didn't want to post it as an answer because the below answers better resolve the actual question of why calc isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't write it correctly 
you need to add spaces between the operator "-"

```css
article {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #FF9800, rgba(255, 235, 59, .91) 87%), url(http://ably.ir/Uploads/SQL%20Server/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Tutorial.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  color: #263238;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

article:after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  background: #263238;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-md-12">
  <h2>something</h2>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternate solution to have left/right and top/bottom size 2px less than the parent size is to use `right: 2px` and `bottom: 2px` to your absolute position element:

```css
article {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #FF9800, rgba(255, 235, 59, .91) 87%), url(http://ably.ir/Uploads/SQL%20Server/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Tutorial.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  color: #263238;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

article:after {
  content: "";
  /*width: calc(100% - 4px);*/
  /*height: calc(100% - 4px);*/
  background: #263238;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px; right:2px;
  top: 2px; bottom:2px;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-md-12">
  <h2>something</h2>
</article>
```

This has better performance (as its not required to recalculate properties on special events) and better browser support

Answer (score 1):

Add space between value and operator in calc function

```
calc(<value> <operator> <value>)
```

for example

```
width: calc(100% - 4px);
height: calc(100% - 4px);
```